# Correct usage subclassing a spring ContextLoader for testing

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-annotations, spring-test

For the integration tests for my spring application with junit I am subclassing `org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader`, because I want to use a already present `XmlWebApplicationContext` for wiring up my test class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=MyContextLoader.class)
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    public AccountDao accountDao;
}
```

The implementation of my ContextLoader is as follows:

public class MyContextLoader implements ContextLoader {

```
    @Override
    public String[] processLocations(Class<?> clazz, String... locations) {
        return locations;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationContext loadContext(String... locations) throws Exception {
        try {
            // Start Embedded Tomcat
            EmbeddedTomcat tomcat = new EmbeddedTomcat("mas", 8080);
            tomcat.launch();

            Context rootContext = tomcat.getRootContext();
            ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = (ContextLoaderListener) rootContext.getApplicationLifecycleListeners()[0];
            XmlWebApplicationContext context = (XmlWebApplicationContext) contextLoaderListener.getContext();


            GenericApplicationContext c = new GenericApplicationContext(context);
            AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(c);

            //context.refresh();
            //context.registerShutdownHook();

            return context;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }   
    }   
}
```

When putting a breakpoint in the `loadContext(...)` method I can call getBean(AccountDao.class) and everything works fine. However, it seems that my test class actually is not autowired. I debugged a little and stepped through the spring code and it seems that in the method AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(String beanName, AbstractBeanDefinition mbd, BeanWrapper bw) the PropertyValues are not set for my class Test.

Maybe, am I setting up the Annotation Processing wrong?

Information to the code: As you might guess and see, I am doing an integration test and therefore starting an embedded tomcat server in order to test my RESTful webservice. How getting the application context with a "hack" from an embedded tomcat is shown in my post here: [Getting Access to Spring with Embedded Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232049/getting-access-to-spring-with-embedded-tomcat-6)

I am looking forward to your replies.
Erik

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're creating a new `GenericApplicationContext`, which is not the one that Spring uses to autowire the test bean.